# Chrome "access-Control-Allow-Origin" header for origin error (CORS)

Tags: google-chrome, http, cors, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following setup:

1. Webserver 1 https://localhost:8888
2. Webserver 2 https://localhost:9005
3. Webserver 3 https://localhost:9006

I open https://localhost:8888 from a Web browser and enter the following JS code.

```
(async () => {
    const endpointId = '1d60eb5195725648';
    const continueUrl = 'https://localhost:9006/'
    const signinUrl = new URL('https://localhost:9005/_login');
    signinUrl.searchParams.set('continue', continueUrl);
    signinUrl.searchParams.set('endpoint', endpointId);
    const response = await fetch(signinUrl.toString(), {     
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}`,
        },
    });
})();
```

I'm getting this error in my Chrome Browser Version 102.0.5005.115

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:9006/?TOKEN=0<Truncated>c&endpoint=1d60eb5195725648' (redirected from 'https://localhost:9005/_login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9006%2F&endpoint=1d60eb5195725648') from origin 'https://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:8888' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Looks like Origin field is correct according to the info in Headers. What am I missing?

(I truncated Token to improve readability)

Requests:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:9005/_login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9006%2F&endpoint=1d60eb5195725648
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:9005
Referrer Policy: origin

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Proxy-Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:8888
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 12 Jun 2022 02:47:09 GMT

--

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:9005
Origin: https://localhost:8888
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://localhost:8888/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

```
Request URL: https://localhost:9005/_login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9006%2F&endpoint=1d60eb5195725648
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:9005
Referrer Policy: origin

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:8888
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 360
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 12 Jun 2022 02:47:09 GMT
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Location: https://localhost:9006/?TOKEN=00cfdab4e480656ed7d71b3e58df42fe5422d85d33118a5af5fb7cc66f2d81330b46740ccbca4927ecfe841e751f0de72fdf53c4eb7d66b7c5ab857e33c6beaa270950fe0c49047fd5260db3120731d0abbfe3be1a0d316db4b0754610c81e2b070cea24e46e0e5ef76937c65832ef7c315b452b846e87f59be3124478cee49045162c&endpoint=1d60eb5195725648
Pragma: no-cache

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM8mfOksOCl6l4O13z5PQv1cUVgKDKWgbo_rNXDL_Fw_-aedVVJdAFOSYByUjEy1WYrAKoik0KHx_c69aCXZcuAXbYedYkZRtDb5Y3Bz98eqjrOBjT0XrWspWdGNqRvsq_L_rDERdnsUFDFKCNiFCHV4sg
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1057744305.1654277711; _gid=GA1.1.1514740287.1654641546; _gat=1
Host: localhost:9005
Origin: https://localhost:8888
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://localhost:8888/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

```
Request URL: https://localhost:9006/?TOKEN=00cfdab4e480656ed7d71b3e58df42fe5422d85d33118a5af5fb7cc66f2d81330b46740ccbca4927ecfe841e751f0de72fdf53c4eb7d66b7c5ab857e33c6beaa270950fe0c49047fd5260db3120731d0abbfe3be1a0d316db4b0754610c81e2b070cea24e46e0e5ef76937c65832ef7c315b452b846e87f59be3124478cee49045162c&endpoint=1d60eb5195725648
Referrer Policy: origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Referer: https://localhost:8888/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Either (unsafely) change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` being sent to allow any origin,or else make the request to `https://localhost:9006` directly — rather than to `https://localhost:9005`. Those are the only two options. The error cited in the question occurs because the request made to the `https://localhost:9005` URL gets redirected across origins to a `https://localhost:9006` URL. When that cross-origin redirect occurs, the browser changes the request origin to `null`, which doesn’t match `https://localhost:8888`, and so the browser blocks your frontend code from reading the response.

Comment: After changing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to "*" I get `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t say change it to `*`. Just changing it to `*` will just give you the error you cited. So to allow any origin, you’d instead need to have your server-side code read the value of the `Origin` request header and then set the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the same value. But doing that when you’re also including credentials is unsafe. So you don’t really want to do that. The only safe option is to make the request to the `https://localhost:9006` URL directly, rather than making the request to `https://localhost:9005` and having it redirect.